# How to save an array of strings using mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this schema to represent a user:

```js
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    social: [{
        facebook: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        twitter: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        }
    }]
});
```

how can I save values using this schema? What I am doing so far:

```js
user.username = username;
user.social['facebook'] = facebook;
user.social['twitter'] = twitter;

await user.save();
```

this works for username but social is still an empty array. I also tried

```js
user.social.facebook = facebook;
user.social.twitter = twitter;
```

same result:

```js
 "social" : [ ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you really want `social` field to be an array? Since it stores `facebook` and `twitter` accounts, it is logical that each user will have only one of these accounts. In that case, it is better if you define `social` to be object with nested properties. That is easier to maintain and it will work with your code.

```js
social: {
  facebook: { type: String, required: false },
  twitter: { type: String, required: false }
}
```

---

If you really need `social` field to be an array, you can change your code like this:

```js
user.username = username;
user.social[0] = {
  'facebook': facebook,
  'twitter': twitter,
};

await user.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `social` is an array of `objects`. Shouldn't you be doing

```
user.social[0].facebook = facebook;
user.social[0].twitter = twitter;
```

Right now you are trying to access property on object, but social is an array of objects